# Is there any way in which dual boot can affect battery life?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, battery

I just dual booted my dell xps 13 9370 with win 10 and ubuntu 18.0.4 but I've found that after the dual boot my battery life is significantly less even if I'm using only Win 10. Is there any way that the dual boot is affecting my battery life.

(Specs: i7,16gb ram)

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know for sure, but Lenovo has been warning against dualboot in some cases where it conflicts with their energy management stuff. If Dell has similar energy management that runs as part of the firmware (and it probably does in order to talk to the battery smarts) then this would explain certain differences. Research in SuperUser for those hints.